# Python Turtle write() syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have a Problem. I am learning Python i get a EOL Error. I searching for a solution but i find nothing.

```
def gefangen(mx,my):
  if not geschafft:
    paula.write('Super, du hast Paula erwischt!')
  else:
    paula.write('Das zählt ja wohl nicht?!')
    onclick(start) # Mauskoordinaten werden
    paula.onclick(gefangen) # automatisch übergeben
  while paula.distance(horst) > 4:
    horst.fd(randint(3,7))
    horst.lt(randint(-20,40)/10)
    paula.setheading(paula.towards(horst))
    paula.fd(randint(1,10))
  if count % 20 == 0:
    horst.stamp()
    paula.stamp()
    count += 1
  if horst.ycor()<-260 or horst.xcor()>310:
    horst.write('Puh, geschafft!')
    paula.write('Mist, entwischt!')
    geschafft=True
  break
  if not geschafft:
    horst.write("Erwischt!",font=("Arial",14,"bold")")
    pu()
    goto(-200,-200)
    shape("circle")
    write("Noch einmal? Hier klicken")
    pd()
    st()
```

http://prntscr.com/gstq0d i get this error (look screenshot)

Comment: Make sure your code is properly indented. Python is very space sensitive and I see a `break` outside your loop.

Comment: Don't post screenshot. Post text please. And format it properly.

Comment: Take a look at the syntax highlighting. The syntax error is near the point where the syntax highlighting starts going crazy.

Comment: The Formatting was not great. but thx for help. sry i am new. you can close this

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extra double quote at `"bold")")` ...

```
if not geschafft:
    horst.write("Erwischt!",font=("Arial",14,"bold")")
```

Answer (score 0):

horst.write("Erwischt!",font=("Arial",14,"bold")")

In this line, You have given an extra double quotes at the end.